# Использование js после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста решить одну проблему(Если она вообще решается путем js)...
Есть сайт, на нем нужно авторизоваться с помощью email. Пишу в console браузера скрипт, который будет автоматически авторизовываться и вводить естественно данные в форму логин и пароль.. Но вот же проблема, при клике на кнопку "Авторизоваться с помощью Email" - у меня страница обновляется и мой скрипт так же перестает выполняться, как можно сделать что бы после обновления страницы мой скрипт продолжил выполняться?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для этого надо писать расширение для браузера

Comment: Ну или на selenium unit testing
Написал тест который бы заполнял твои поля и отслеживал бы изменения. А с помощью JS у тебя не получиться.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду все таки пробовать с помощью расширения сделать.